# issues debugging using VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, office-js

I'm developing an office-js taskpane add-in for Excel.
I am using VS code as the IDE and debugging environment.
After running a debug, more often than not I cannot run a second debugging session because VS code does not launch WebPack.
I end each debugging session simply by closing Excel. That also ends the session according to the VS code terminal. But if I hit F5 again, Excel starts immediately and webpack does not. I have to reboot the machine to get it working again.

Does anyone here know how I might fix this extremely annoying issue?

Comment: Have you followed the instructions here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-with-vs-extension

Comment: I tended to stop debugging by closing the Excel app. I'll try using stop debugging from VS Code today, see if that resolves the issues. VSCode does detect closure of the app and then also closes Webpack and tells me it has ended the debugging session, which led me to believe this isn't a bad way to stop debugging.

Comment: From what I've seen, debugging Office Add-ins can just be a bit finicky. I found a few other debugging links you may find helpful. I will post them in a comment.

Comment: I can now confirm stopping the debug session from VS code is no guarantee that it will work next time 'round. :-/

Comment: More often than not, if debugging fails, a series of msedge.exe processes are left behind. Sometimes killing those after closing VSCode and then reopeneing VSCode suffices to be able to launch a new debugging session. If that fails, a reboot of Windows is necessary

Comment: If you're still having debugging problems with VSCode, it may not hurt to look into using Visual Studio. The debugging experience may be better there.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few links you may find helpful in debugging Office Add-ins:

[Debug Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-overview)

[Attach a debugger from the task pane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/attach-debugger-from-task-pane)

[Sideloading and Debugging Outlook Add-ins](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qD6eTKjg4fE)